# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 Grub Issue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, gpt

I am trying to dual boot windows 7 (3TB hard drive) and Ubuntu 14.04 (1TB hard drive). I already have windows installed and am trying to install Ubuntu, however, the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 is not shown. This may have to do with the GPT partition table I am using for windows, since I am using a 3TB hard drive. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to recognize a GPT partition table?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got two separate hard disks, I recommend using the "Something Else" partitioning option; I'm not sure if the more automatic options will work with multiple disks. Besides, you know where you want things to go, and the installer doesn't.

Ubuntu has long supported GPT; that's not an issue. You should be wary, though, of boot modes. If Windows is installed to a GPT disk, it must be booting in EFI mode. If you install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, that will create complications. See [my page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/), [this Ubuntu documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), or [this askubuntu question about installing Ubuntu and Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). You shouldn't need to do anything special because of your second disk, aside from using the "Something Else" partitioning option.